# PhoneGap keeps overwriting my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, xcode, cordova

I've looked (almost) everywhere - to no avail.

The issue I am having is this:

I am developing an iOS App using PhoneGap and jQuery. I have been compiling my code and running it on an emulator and an iPhone 5. Everything was going smoothly till today.
Today, after modifying the HTML/JS code, I went to run it again and it keeps overwriting my HTML/JS files with old code (code from before today). I have no idea why this is happening :\

I haven't changed anything other than the HTML/JS code, no settings or config data have been changed.

Have any of you ever experienced this before with PhoneGap? Please don't hesitate to ask for more info if it helps in diagnosis - I can provide the build log if required but I'm not sure how much help that would be.

Comment: Where are you doing your edits?

Comment: @bhargavg, In a plain text code editor (Coda)

Comment: :) I meant which location in your directory structure

Comment: @bhargavg, ah right, sorry. The path is... mate, you just solved my question! - I was editing in the platforms/ios/www directory! I should have been editing in the root www directory!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bhargavg, I've managed to solve this dilema!

Instead of editing code in the root www directory, I was editing it in the platforms/ios/www directory.
I hope this helps anyone else stuck in the same parallax :)